# Window embedding under Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, qt

How to embed the window of process A into the window of process B using object-c under Mac. Sorry, I am not familiar with this aspect and I cannot find useful relevant information online. I hope someone can help me answer this question.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYTSE.png)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <objc/objc-runtime.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/NSRunningApplication.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget mainWindow;
    NSString *targetProcessName = @"com.apple.TextEdit";

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSArray<NSRunningApplication *> *runningApps = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.TextEdit"];
        for (NSRunningApplication *appImbed in runningApps) {
            // how to get NSWindow
            NSArray *windowsTmp = [appImbed windows];
            for (NSWindow *windowTmp in windowsTmp)
            {
                NSLog(@"Window Title: %@", [windowTmp title]);
            }
        }
    }
    mainWindow.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: A few days have passed. Can anyone answer this question? I need help